# webpack loader inline file in dist folder

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I have a question about the inline.js file in the dist folder of my angular2 project. I Know inline.js is a webpack loader but when  I open and see the inline.js file code, I do see an IIFE just like jquery but how it is loading all modules and how come it has no dependency as the code does not look like a plain javascript code as in the case of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iniline.js` is a webpack utility bundle. Basically has some util functions for webpack to do it's job, things like bundle async loading, loading bundle chunks ..etc

in response to `"how come it has no dependency"` and 
`"the code does not look like a plain javascript code "`:

It is vanilla "plain" `js` code, might be slightly hard to follow but it is vanilla `js`

Comment: It is a Vanila Javascript..wow..I again take a look with a cool mind...Thanks  @Ahmed Musallam